# How can we plot horizontal prediction bands?

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics

**1. Problem statement**

Some game days before the end of a league season I want to show the possible final rankings (depending upon the results of the outstanding games).

**2. Example data** (situation after the penultimate game day)

```
data =
  <|"Bayern" -> <|"High" -> 1, "Now" -> 1, "Low" -> 1|>,
   "Leipzig" -> <|"High" -> 2, "Now" -> 2, "Low" -> 2|>,
   "Dortmund" -> <|"High" -> 3, "Now" -> 3, "Low" -> 4|>,
   "Wolsburg" -> <|"High" -> 3, "Now" -> 4, "Low" -> 4|>,
   "Frankfurt" -> <|"High" -> 5, "Now" -> 5, "Low" -> 5|>,
   "Leverkusen" -> <|"High" -> 6, "Now" -> 6, "Low" -> 6|>,
   "Union" -> <|"High" -> 7, "Now" -> 7, "Low" -> 10|>,
   "Gladbach" -> <|"High" -> 7, "Now" -> 8, "Low" -> 10|>,
   "Stuttgart" -> <|"High" -> 7, "Now" -> 9, "Low" -> 10|>,
   "Freiburg" -> <|"High" -> 7, "Now" -> 10, "Low" -> 10|>,
   "Hoffenheim" -> <|"High" -> 11, "Now" -> 11, "Low" -> 11|>,
   "Augsburg" -> <|"High" -> 12, "Now" -> 12, "Low" -> 14|>,
   "Mainz" -> <|"High" -> 12, "Now" -> 13, "Low" -> 14|>,
   "Hertha" -> <|"High" -> 12, "Now" -> 14, "Low" -> 15|>,
   "Bielefeld" -> <|"High" -> 14, "Now" -> 15, "Low" -> 17|>,
   "Bremen" -> <|"High" -> 15, "Now" -> 16, "Low" -> 17|>,
   "Koeln" -> <|"High" -> 15, "Now" -> 17, "Low" -> 17|>,
   "Schalke" -> <|"High" -> 18, "Now" -> 18, "Low" -> 18|>|>;
```

**3. Corresponding Plot**

[image]

- Red: Actual ranking
- White: Best possible ranking after last game day
- Black: Worst possible ranking after last game day

A few matchdays earlier the prediction bands might have looked like this:

[image]

**4. Question**

What could be possible ways to produce a similar Plot (except the logos)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ds = Dataset[data];

styleCode = Association[Join[
   Thread[ToString /@ Range[Length@ds] -> ""], 
   Thread[ToString /@ Range[#High, #Low] -> 
     (Range[#High, #Low] /. 
       {Except[#High | #Low, _Integer] -> Style["", Darker@Darker@Gray], 
        #High ->  Style[#High, White, Bold, FontColor -> Black], 
        #Low ->   Style[#Low, Black, Bold,  FontColor -> White]})], 
   {ToString @ #Now -> Style[#Now, Darker @ Red, Bold, FontColor -> White]}]]&;

options = {HeaderBackground -> {Lighter @ LightGray, White}, 
   ItemSize -> 3.5, 
   MaxItems -> {All, All}, 
   Alignment -> {Center, Automatic}, 
   ItemStyle -> {All -> {FontSize -> 20}}, 
   Background -> {{{Lighter @ Lighter @ Gray, Lighter @ LightGray}}, 
     If[Head[#] === Style, #[[2]]] &}};

Dataset[ds[All, styleCode], options]
```

[image]

**See also:**

[Christopher Carlson, New 12.1 Dataset Interactive Controls and Formatting Options](https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/06/23/new-12-1-dataset-interactive-controls-formatting-options/)

Comment: I am extremely amazed - wonderful!